# How can I retrieve records or views from entity?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to get values from these attributes:

```
class Program
{
    private static OrganizationService _orgService;

     private static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         ClientCredentials cre = new ClientCredentials();
         cre.UserName.UserName = "login";
         cre.UserName.Password = "password";

         Uri serviceUri = new Uri("some_adress");

         OrganizationServiceProxy proxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(serviceUri, null, cre, null);
         proxy.EnableProxyTypes();
         IOrganizationService service = (IOrganizationService) proxy;

         retrieveEntityRequest = new RetrieveEntityRequest
         {
             EntityFilters = EntityFilters.All,
             LogicalName = "new_sms_parameters",
             RetrieveAsIfPublished = true
         };

         retrieveEntityResponse = (RetrieveEntityResponse) service.Execute(retrieveEntityRequest);
         currentEntity = retrieveEntityResponse.EntityMetadata;

         // Attributes


         foreach (AttributeMetadata allattributes in currentEntity.Attributes)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("SMS Parameters: " +   allattributes.LogicalName);
         }
     }
}
```

Here I connect to CRM and get attributes name, but I not have an idea how I can get these values. What can I do next?

Comment: you have return type void; change to appropriate return type like string array and return respectively.

Answer (score 1):

`RetrieveEntityRequest` is for getting metadata that describes an entity, for example; number of fields, types of field, like string, int, etc.

If you want to get record information you need to use [Retrieve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservice.retrieve.aspx) to get a single record by Id, or [RetrieveMultiple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservice.retrievemultiple.aspx) to get multiple records based on a query.

Check the links above for full examples, but effectively:

```
ColumnSet attributes = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "name", "ownerid", "address1_postalcode" });

account = service.Retrieve(account.LogicalName, accountId, attributes);

String postcode = account["address1_postalcode"];
String alsoPostcode = account.GetAttributeValue<String>("address1_postalcode");
```

Comment: How I can get the id?

Comment: Well its from a record in CRM, so lots of different ways to get it. Using `RetrieveMultiple` you can search by other attribute values.